# How to Propagate event in bubbling phase?

Tags: apache-flex

this is my code and i want to fire event by this order clickme, windowID and panId.

By default its happening in reverse order.

---

here is my code:

```
import mx.controls.Alert;

public function init() : void
{
  window.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function h() :void {mx.controls.Alert.show('window clicked');});
  panel.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function h() :void {mx.controls.Alert.show('panel clicked');});
  btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,function h() :void {mx.controls.Alert.show('btn clicked');});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to trigger the event listeners on the parents first, then you should use the capture phase, not the bubbling phase.

Try using:

```
interactiveObject.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, someClickHandler, true);
```

where the [useCapture](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener%28%29) argument is set to `true`.

The order of event propagation is:

1. **Capture** phase, propagates from *Parent -> Child*; then
2. **Target** phase (which is where `currentTarget == target`); and lastly
3. **Bubbling** phase, which propagates back out from *Child -> Parent*.